# Generic type 'GraphQLObjectType<TSource, TContext>' requires between 0 and 2 type arguments

Tags: typescript, express, prisma, prisma-graphql

I created a basic Graphql Typescript App using Apollo server and I am using Prisma and I am currently trying to build so that I can deploy and I keep getting 7 error each time I run build

[Error on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LThlJ.jpg)

[Node Modules file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DYg5.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlEDf.png)

here is the GitHub
https://github.com/chineduknight/EasyWash_backend

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Luckily I found [this](https://github.com/graphql-nexus/schema/issues/111) issue and really helped me. I removed `graphql@15.2.0` & installed some "older" version of **GraphQL**, the `graphql@15.0.0` and it all worked well.

> **Note:** This happened to me with TypeScript (TS) & by compiling with `tsc`.

I hope this helps you and solves your issue too.